# How do I fix this error where not in " "

Tags: django

I'm working with postgresql

if I delete a.school not in, it works well

```
cursor.execute('create temp table paso as(SELECT b.username as user__username ,count(a.name) as tot FROM principal_student a join users_user b ON  a.user_id = b.id join principal_cycle c ON c.id = a.cycle_id 
WHERE a.school not in ("student not It has school age","You do not have school age") AND (c.status=true) group by a.name,b.username order by b.username)');

cursor.execute('Select a.user__username,count(a.tot) from paso a group by user__username order by total desc')

        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            results.append(dict(zip(columns,row)))

        context['prod'] = results       
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting against which cursor.execute? It is unclear what we are debugging.

Comment: column "student not It has school age" does not exist

Comment: and try to put 'student not It has school age' and follows the debug

Comment: Are fields like 'user__username' for real? That looks more like the Django ORM notation for foreign keys. Anyway why are you using raw sql for simple tasks like this with django?

Comment: it's just an  "as" , The mistake is in quotes, but not like writing the select
with the where a.school not in ('xxx', 'xxx'). You know how to translate this select orm  create temp table paso as(SELECT b.username as user__username ,count(a.name) as tot FROM principal_student a join users_user b ON  a.user_id = b.id join principal_cycle c ON c.id = a.cycle_id 
WHERE a.school not in ("student not It has school age","You do not have school age") AND (c.status=true) group by a.name,b.username order by b.username)');